# MVC3 Telerik Grid - How to submit all rows to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

By default it looks like Telerik Grid for MVC3 submits only the rows marked as "dirty" to my controller.  I need to be able to submit all rows on a Telerik Grid to my controller.  In other words I think I need to mark all rows as changed so the grid will send all rows to my controller.

I am using Ajax data binding as in:

.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
                                          .Ajax()
                                          .Select("GetData", "ModuleAccess", new { roleId = @ViewBag.RoleId, appId = @ViewBag.AppId })
                                          .Update("SaveBatchEditing", "ModuleAccess")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
function ModuleAccessGridHasChanges() {
        var grid = $("#ModuleAccessGrid").data("tGrid");
        if (grid != null) {
                var additionalValues = grid.data;
                if (!$.telerik.trigger(grid.element, 'submitChanges', { values: additionalValues })) {
                    grid.sendValues($.extend({}, additionalValues), 'updateUrl', 'submitChanges');
            }
        }
    }
```

Fiddler shows all the data for the grid coming accross:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<BarcodeListModel>()
                        .Name("orders-grid")
                        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("onDataBinding"))
                        .DataKeys(keys =>
                          {
                              keys.Add(x => x.Id);
                           })
                        .ToolBar(commands =>
                            {
                                commands.SubmitChanges();
                            })
                        .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                                       dataBinding.Ajax()
                                        .Select("BulkEditSelect", "ProductVariant")
                                       .Update("BulkEditSaveBarcode", "ProductVariant")
                                        .Delete("DeleteBarcode", "ProductVariant")
                                     )
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(x => x.Id).ReadOnly();
                            columns.Bound(x => x.SKU);
                            columns.Bound(x => x.barcode);
                            //columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
                            //    .Template(x => Html.ActionLink(T("Admin.Common.View").Text, "DeleteBarcode", new { id = x.Id }))
                            //    .ClientTemplate("<a href=\"DeleteBarcode/<#= Id #>\">" + "Delete" + "</a>")
                            //    .Width(50)
                            //    .Centered()
                            //    .HeaderTemplate("DeleteBarcode")
                            //    .Filterable(false)
                            //    .Title("Delete");
                            columns.Command(commands => commands.Delete()).Width(180);
                        })
                        .Pageable(settings => settings.PageSize(gridPageSize).Position(GridPagerPosition.Both))
                        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("BarcodeList", "ProductVariant", Model))
                        .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)) 
                        .EnableCustomBinding(true)

                  )
```

use like this code

Comment: Your code sample does not work for me.  Which part of it is telling the grid to send all rows on update to the controller?